# What is the mime type for .QFS files or how to write to SD card without mentioning mimeType

Tags: android, mime-types, android-external-storage

I need to write a file of type .QFS to android external SD card. I need mime type to use documentFile.createFile(mimeType, File name) command to create file.

Can anyone please help me with either mimeType or is there any other way to create a file in android version 5.0 and above in external sd card without using the DocumentFile.createFile command.

Comment: I guess you need [Android: Create a file and write to external storage](https://mytechead.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/android-create-a-file-and-write-to-external-storage/) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330276/write-a-file-in-external-storage-in-android).

Comment: This will fail in android version 4.4 and above since android has restricted external sd card usage.

Answer (score -1):

This [blog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) says - `getExternalFilesDirs()` and `getExternalCacheDirs()` will return directories that we can use on “real” external storage.

Add this in your activity for requesting runtime permission:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{ Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_FOR_STORAGE);//REQUEST_FOR_STORAGE=1111
    } else {
//Do your stuff here
            }
...

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

if(requestCode == REQUEST_FOR_STORAGE){

   //Do your stuff here
  }
 }
```

Or may be by removing and resetting the `sdcard write permission` in the Android manifest file.

FYI: [Unable to create file on removeable sdcard in Android 5.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780740/unable-to-create-file-on-removeable-sdcard-in-android-5-0-1) and [How to access external memory in Android Lollipop and above](http://www.raviyp.com/android/192-how-to-access-external-memory-in-android-lollipop-and-above-solution)

Also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305100/cannot-create-directory-in-external-storage-although-permissions-are-apparently).